# How to create a temporary table in Oracle SQL and add data to it?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have built cohorts of accounts based on date of first usage of our service. I need to use these cohorts in a handful of different queries, but don't want to have to create the queries in each of these downstream queries.
 *Reason:* Getting the data the first time took more than 60 minutes, so i don't want to pay that tax for all the other queries.

I know that I could do a statement like the below:

```
WHERE  ACCOUNT_ID IN ('1234567','7891011','1213141'...)
```

But, I'm wondering if there is a way to create a temporary table that I prepopulate with my data, something like

```
WITH MAY_COHORT AS ( SELECT ACCOUNT_ID  Account_ID, '1234567' Account_ID, '7891011' Account_ID, '1213141' )
```

I know that the above won't work, but would appreciate any advice or counsel here.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, you're already on the right track, just an adjustment to your CTE should work:

```
WITH MAY_COHORT AS ( SELECT Account_ID from TableName WHERE ACCOUNT_ID IN ('1234567','7891011','1213141'...) )
```

This *should* give you the May_Cohort table to use for subsequent queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a sub-select for your Ids (no `WITH MY_COHORT`):

```
WHERE  ACCOUNT_ID IN (
          SELECT Account_ID 
            from TableName "Where ... your condition to build your cohort ..." )
```